# File upload with mysql and php

Tags: php

OK I decided to retry it into another way.. This is my code the bad part is now it keep saying invalid file size.

```
<?php
      session_start();
      include "connect.php";
      if ( $_POST[ "submit" ] ) {
             if ( $_SESSION[ "name" ] ) {
                    $name = $_FILES[ "file" ][ "name" ];
                    $type = $_FILES[ "file" ][ "type" ];
                    $size = $_FILES[ "file" ][ "size" ];
                    $tmp_name = $_FILES[ "file" ][ "tmp_name" ];
                    $error = $_FILES[ "file" ][ "error" ];
                    if ( $type == "image/jpeg" || $type == "image/gif" ) {
                           if ( $size > 1100000 && $size < 1700000 ) {
                                  if ( $error > 0 ) {
                                         echo "Error!!!!!!" . $error;
                                  } else {
                                         if ( file_exists( "upload/" . $name ) ) {
                                                echo $name . " already exists.";
                                         }
                                  }
                           } else {
                                  $location = "upload/" . $name;
                                  move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name , $location );
                                  $user = $_SESSION[ "name" ];
                                  $sqlcode = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO tblFile (id,user,location) VALUES ('','$user','$location')" );
                                  echo "<a href='$location'>Click here to view your image.</a>";
                           }
                    }
             } else {

                    echo "Please check the size of your File..";
             }
      } else {
             echo "Invalid file format.";
      }

 ?>
```

the index is:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = "Admin";

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">

Select File: <input type="file" name="uploadFile">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000"/>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload File">

</form>
```

If it is not one thing with this file/upload it is something else. I still have to be able to   user uploads a .png or .jpg file, resize the image to a thumbnail and keep a copy of both the thumbnail and regular size image in a folder. And be able to insert the data into a new table in your database. I think I am alittle closer than before.

Comment: I tried to edit some of your code but it's far too messy. Please _clean it up_ so that the people who try to help can actually read it. Use the format I started with please.

Comment: ok i decided to go another way.. the only thing is it keeps saying invaild file size.

Comment: Where does it say invalid file size? what says invalid file size? give us something work with!

Comment: after you click on the button to upload it comes back and says invalid size

Comment: If the error "Please check the size of your File.." is the one you're referring to, can you reconstruct your if-else **remove the `if($_SESSION['name'])`**? Quite confused what is it for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I have reconstructed and 'clean' your code.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connect.php";

if($_POST['submit']) {
   $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
   $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
   $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
   $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];
   if($type == "image/jpeg" || $type == "image/gif" || $type == "image/pjpeg")
   {
     if($size > 1100000 && $size < 1700000)
     {
       if($error > 0)
         echo "Error Upload #: " . $error;
       else
       {
         if(file_exists("upload/" . $name))
           echo $name . " already exists.";
         else
         {
           $location = "upload/" . $name;
           move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name , $location );
           $user = $_SESSION[ "name" ];
           $sqlcode = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO tblFile (id,user,location) VALUES ('','$user','$location')" );
           echo "<a href='$location'>Click here to view your image.</a>";
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        echo "Invalid file size.";
      }
   }
   else
     echo "Invalid file format.";
}
else
    // invalid due to post submit not set
?>
```

And also, apply changes suggested by @jakenoble. `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000"/>`

Answer (score 0):

This line maybe determines your max file size

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000"/>
```

Try increasing it and trying again?

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What the heck is

```
if ( $_SESSION[ "name" ] ) {
```

supposed to accomplish?  This statement failing is resulting in the output that you're getting.

Verify your `if` logic (easily seen by just looking at indent levels) and try again.